# Triage Review: Flagged Audit Question Because It Belongs on CodeReview

Tags: discussion, review-audits

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44610565/choosing-one-element-from-list-according-to-preference)

The question "how can I make it cleaner/better"?

I thought this would be off topic because it is looking for suggestions and not an answer to a problem. So I flagged it but I failed the audit apparently.

Is the correct action just to comment on it, mention `codereview` and say it looks okay? I didn't down-vote because it is well written and understandable.

But I didn't think a flag was necessarily a bad thing but more or less brought more attention to the question from moderators and others.

Comment: This is simply a case where the people that saw the question before you didn't know or care that it's not appropriate for SO, so they upvoted it despite it not meeting the site's guidelines.  The audit, as a result didn't realize that the question isn't appropriate.

Comment: @servy thank you. So let's say I hit 10 of these kinds of audits in a row (understandably highly unlikely)? or what's the point of penalty?

Comment: If you actually ran into enough to get banned (which, as you mention, is highly unlikely) a moderator can manually revoke the ban.  If you don't fail enough to get banned, you don't need to care.  The audits are generally good, enough that it's pretty hard to get banned only failing bad audits.

Comment: @Servy, thanks for the help. Post your comments as answer and I'll accept.

Comment: And it was even answered by a Mod :(